# Where does the text formatting take place?

Tags: xml, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have this part of an XML (which I got from an external source)

```
> <ListOfStructuredNote>
>                     <StructuredNote>
>                         <GeneralNote>Part APart B</GeneralNote>
>                         <NoteID>Info record PO text</NoteID>
>                         <Agency>
>                             <AgencyCoded>Other</AgencyCoded>
>                             <AgencyCodedOther>asdasd</AgencyCodedOther>
>                         </Agency>
>                     </StructuredNote>
>  </ListOfStructuredNote>
```

The (complete) XML will be parsed with Lotusscript. The function: `CreateDOMParser` will be used to parse the XML.

Eventually I need the value of the GeneralNote element which is Inside the element: ListOfStructure. With the following code I can retrieve the value of GeneralNote and put it into a variable called : note which is of type String. The code in Lotusscript:

```
ret = getFieldValue(Node, "ListOfStructuredNote", "String")
note = ""
If Not ChildNode Is Nothing Then
    numChildren =  ChildNode.NumberOfChildNodes
    Set child = ChildNode.FirstChild     ' Get child
    While numChildren > 0

    If Child.NodeType = 1 Then
        If Not Child.FirstChild.FirstChild.isNull Then
            note = note + Child.FirstChild.FirstChild.NodeValue
        End If
    End If

    Set child = child.NextSibling   ' Get next child
    numChildren = numChildren - 1
Wend
End If
```

When the variable note is saved into a Lotus Document field (type text list) then I see this as output:
Part A(newline)
Part B

How is it possible that there is a newline. Because if I open the XML in a text editor like vscode or sublime text 3, then I do not see any newline. So what I am asking is: How can I detect any formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different text editor with a feature that shows hidden characters.

For example, use Notepad++ and select View - Show Symbol - Show All Characters. You'll probably find that there really is something there between Part A and Part B.

Comment: Most probable there is a Linux Line break. If there is no notepad++ try wordpad: it will show the linebreak where notepad does not.

Comment: Agreed it's almost certainly a line break. I just wanted to leave that part of the learning process for the OP to discover  ;-)

Comment: unfortunately i did not find any line break :( also checked it in Hex codes nothing found

Comment: Accepted the answer because the way posted by Richard seems to be the correct way to show hidden characters.